# Adwords ad group quality score

Tags: keywords, google-ads, ppc

I've heard some Pay Per Click consultants claim that having poor performing keywords in an ad group effects the quality score of other keywords and Google uses a form of quality score for the entire ad group.

Are quality scores for keywords independent of other keywords?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to back up however we've had experience with what seem like two identical campaigns in different accounts, one which has been around for several years but plagued with bad quality score ads and the other account fairly new.  The bids for the old account for the same keywords were more expensive; supporting the theory that there is an underlying *account level Quality Score*.

We work hard to ensure that quality score is good so that we don't risk the reputation of the entire account.  So in summary yes, it wouldn't hurt to assume that there is an account level quality score and having poor quality ads may affect the other ad-groups.